# Create App Package using MakeAppx commands

Tags: windows, desktop-app-converter

I have converted my Exe using Desktop App Converter tool using following commands :

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> DesktopAppConverter.exe -Installer C:\Installer\Technician.exe -InstallerArguments "/S" -Destination C:\Newfolder -PackageName "Technician" -Publisher "CN=30910EF5-407B-4B34-B55F-DD7136DDCA98" -Version 5.5.0.0 -Verbose
```

Output :

```
PackageFilesPath           C:\Newfolder\Technician\PackageFiles
```

No when I Try to create App Package using MakeAppx commands :

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> MakeAppx pack -d "C:\Newfolder\Technician\PackageFiles" -p "C:\Technician.appx"
```

Error :

```
MakeAppx : The term 'MakeAppx' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

**Not able to create App Package using  MakeAppx commands.**

I am using Windows 10 Enterprise 64 bit Os Version 10.0.14393 and SDK (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64) 10.0.16299.0

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

For me, this exact error was the result of MULTIPLE %PATHS% not being available to ADMIN:CMD.

Here were environment variables needed too get MS BRIDGE DAC commands to work:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.1.4.0_x64__8e...\

Answer (score 0):

No sure what is source of your error, but maybe you can try the following option/tool to generate your appx. It's GUI based, so much easier to use than all the command lines of the Desktop App Converter or MakeAppX.exe

This is a new [free Express edition from Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/express-edition.html), developed in partnership with Microsoft, its purpose is to complement the Desktop App Converter.

As I said, it has a GUI that allows for advanced customization of the APPX packages, without requiring you to have knowledge about the internals package schemas.

If you have any questions about it, let me know, would love to help.

*Disclaimer: I work on the team that builds Advanced Installer.*